# $n$-body problem = many-body problem?

Tags: terminology, many-body

Are the terms "$n$-body problem" and "many-body problem" synonymous? Or does one refer to a numerical problem an the other to an analytical problem?

Comment: As far as I know, yes the are they same.

Comment: It depends on the context, I would say.

Comment: I've never seen anyone talk about an $n$-body problem with $n=1$ or $2$. The only other possible difference I see is that the $n$-body terminology fixes the number of particle, while in QFT you have Fock space with superposition of states with different number of particles. I'd be interested to see any other context dependent usage.

Comment: Whenever you hear a term like "n-body problem", it must come with a definition of the included variables. If "n" is not defined along with the term, this term essentially is meaningless.

Comment: @Steeven: Maybe semantics, but I tend to (respectfully) disagree: In astrophysics you use the term $N$-body codes as a generic term for particle simulations that do not involve hydrodynamics. A _given_ $N$-body simulation will of course contain a fixed (or variable) number of particles, which in general will vary from run to run. You could thus talk about "solving a problem of structure formation as an $N$-body problem", without specifying any number.

Comment: This is semantics not physics.

Comment: In the cold atoms community, people also study the few-body problem (e.g. Efimov physics, 3-body bound states, etc).

Comment: @my2cts What's the [terminology] tag for, then?

Comment: It is not a good idea to fix the meaning of terms to this degree. Physics should be independent of terminology. So if you say 'n-body' just explain what you mean by it. We don't want to define how much is 'n'. Just that it is an integer variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mathematics Subject Classification (MSC2010)](https://zbmath.org/classification) classifies "many-body" under quantum mechanics:

> [81-XX](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81) [Quantum
>   theory](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81) [149997](/?q=cc%3A81)
>
> [81Vxx](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81V) [Applications to specific physical systems](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81V) [33023](/?q=cc%3A81V)
>
> [81V70](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81V70) [Many-body theory; quantum Hall effect](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81V70)
>   [4367](/?q=cc%3A81V70)

Whereas "$n$-body" appears to have more [extension](https://oed.com/view/Entry/66936#eid4847411):

> [70-XX](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A70) [Mechanics of
>   particles and systems](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A70)
>   [For relativistic mechanics, see
>   [83A05](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A83A05) and
>   [83C10](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A83C10); for
>   statistical mechanics, see
>   [82-XX](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A82%2A)]
>   [62456](/?q=cc%3A70)
>
> [70Fxx](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A70F)
>   [Dynamics of a system of particles, including celestial
>   mechanics](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A70F)
>   [14431](/?q=cc%3A70F)
>
> [70F10](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A70F10)
>   [$n$-body problems](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A70F10)
>   [2495](/?q=cc%3A70F10)
>
> [81-XX](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81) [Quantum
>   theory](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81)
>   [149997](/?q=cc%3A81)
>
> [81Uxx](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81U)
>   [Scattering theory](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81U)
>   [See also [34A55](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A34A55),
>   [34L25](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A34L25),
>   [34L40](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A34L40),
>   [35P25](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A35P25),
>   [47A40](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A47A40)]
>   [8728](/?q=cc%3A81U)
>
> [81U10](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81U10)
>   [$n$-body potential scattering
>   theory](https://zbmath.org/classification/?q=cc%3A81U10)
>   [850](/?q=cc%3A81U10)

APS's [Physics Subject Headings](https://physh.aps.org/) doesn't appear to have "$n$-body," nor does AAS's [Astronomical Subject Keywords](https://journals.aas.org/keywords-2013/) even have "many-body".

The *OED* doesn't have "$n$-body", but it says this for "[many-body](https://oed.com/view/Entry/113819#eid38006628)":

> **many-body** *adj.* relating to or involving three or more bodies or particles; *spec.* with reference to the problem of predicting their positions and motions at any future time given their present values and the way the bodies interact (through collision, gravitational attraction, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

N-body problem refers to the problem of having any number objects with initial positions and velocity and predict their dynamics according to Newton's laws; for n = 2 there are analytical and practical solutions, and though it is proven that analytic solutions exists for n > 3 those are not practical and numerical methods are used instead.

Many-body problems refer to the family of problems pertaining a quantum system with an arbitrary number of particles.

Comment: Not sure where this terminology is defined, but I would agree based on my experience. Astronomers that I know always referred to n-body problems of celestial mechanics. Colleagues that were solid state and condensed matter physicists worked on many-body problems.

Comment: What about the many-body problem in quantum physics?